# Alternative to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file

Tags: ip-address, hosts-file, web-filtering, traffic-filtering, internet-filter

I have a bunch of websites blocked at the system level in my Windows 7 by using the *etc/hosts* file. So far, I've done it the usual way, by giving *127.0.0.1* as the website's IP address.

However, I'd like to be able to know when it's my `hosts` file blocking things, as opposed to my ISP doing it or the server just plain not being available.

It would be useful to be able to specify some IP other than *127.0.0.1* that always returns a quick-loading page which doesn't change with time, as a reminder that I've blocked this URL, so the content doesn't really matter as long as it a simple, fast page with unique content.

Is there any such reliable IP address that responds to non-existing path queries with a distinct-looking, fast loading page (probably an error page, which works for this)?

Or is there any other way of accomplishing this idea (other than keeping a **local web server** continuously running in the background just for this)?

Comment: Depending on your browser, the error message should show the unavailable IP address (http://127.0.0.1). Otherwise, you can redirect to your router's web interface: it won't be an error message, but it will be recognisably distinct.

Comment: Firefox doesn't seem to show the IP, but the router suggestion is quite an interesting possibility. Could you also add that as an answer, which would make it more visible to future visitors too?

Comment: What’s wrong with having a web server running? Using something low-resource like NodeJS, the desired effect could be achieved with almost no code/programming/configuration at all.

Comment: In addition to router configuration pages, some network *printers* run their own web servers where you can view toner levels, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your browser, the error message should show the unavailable IP address (127.0.0.1):-

- Firefox38 shows: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1.
- Chrome43 (*Details*) shows: Google Chrome's connection attempt to **127.0.0.1** was rejected.
- IE11 shows: Make sure that the web address http://127.0.0.1 is correct.

Otherwise, you can redirect to your router's web interface: it won't be an error message, but it will be recognisably distinct.

Comment: I ended up using my firewall's block feature, since I wanted to block all subdomains of the site too (and `hosts` requires each subdomain to be specified individually, no wildcards), and Comodo shows a neat "this website blocked by your admin" page too. That said, the "redirect to router's interface" suggestion is quite useful and something that might come in handy later, so I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I find that 0.0.0.0 is preferable because I run a local web server and 127.0.0.1 is a local loop-back address to my web server. All entries in the hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1 renders the local webserver home or error pages (depending on the request) which takes CPU cycles, memory and  thus time.

0.0.0.0 is instantly rejected and this speeds up the process greatly (for my atypical setup anyway).

I believe Skype also opens port 80 (local web server) which I would imagine would also take time to respond to but I haven't tested this personally.

Answer (score 1):

sundar, with respect to your comment on blocking subdomains with wildcards, there is a tool for Windows called Acrylic DNS Proxy (http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome) which allows just that, much like dnsmask in linux.  (it equates to, however, running a server in background on your machine).